# Brit with a criminal record travelling to Australia. Which visa to apply for?

Tags: visas, australia, criminal-records

I am struggling to find a firm answer to my question. Here's my situation:

I am looking to travel to Australia in December for a few weeks to visit my brother, who moved there a few years ago. I am a British national, but 10 years ago (when I was 18) I made a mistake and landed myself a criminal conviction for a very minor cannabis possession charge, which resulted in a £600 fine. I haven't been in trouble since and it is a huge embarrassment.

Obviously this meets the ETA visa requirement of not having a conviction that resulted in a sentence of more than 12 months. But I don't want to accidentally fall foul of the rules and be seen to have misrepresented myself.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the application form ask any open questions where you could mention this?

Comment: It seems we have boatloads of questions on this site about people with a criminal record coming to Australia.

Answer (score 3):

On the [Australian Dept of Home Affairs - eVisitor subclass 651](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/651-) page => `eVisitor Applicants` tab, => `Who could get this visa`, it states:

> **Criminal Convictions**
>
> If you have had one or more criminal convictions (in any country) for
> which the sentence or sentences (whether served or not) total 12
> months or more you will not be permitted entry to Australia whilst
> holding an eVisitor. If you have had any criminal conviction in any
> country, a more appropriate visa for you to apply for may be a  [Visitor
> visa (subclass 600)](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/600-), rather than an eVisitor.

The Visitor Visa application form requires the applicant to disclose any convictions in any country (part F, Character details. https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/forms/documents/1419.pdf

Comment: This corresponds with what I was told as well. I wanted to apply for an ETA, but I was arrested when I was 14 for a misdemeanor with a $15 fine. I called the Aussie visa folks, and they told me that "because of my criminal history" I had to apply for a visitor visa. Sounds like OP would probably be told the same.